# Which flags do I have to use with du when I want a list with the sizes of the subdirectories?

Tags: command-line, disk-usage

I've got an Ubuntu machine with many home directories.

```
/home/stu123
/home/stu124
/home/stu125
...
```

Considering I'm in the `home` directory: I know that I have to use the `du` command together with the `h` flag to see the size of each directory in B, KB, MB, etc.

But then it it goes recursively into each directory and prints the size of each file.

I like to have the Byte-size of each folder directly underneath "home".

Something like:

```
stu123  458MB
stu124   68MB
stu125  392MB
```

So that I get the Byte-size of each folder as a total sum.

**Is that possible with just `du`?**

Best case would be when the results are shown ordered.

In above example:

```
stu124  68MB
stu125  392MB
stu123  458MB
```

Comment: -1. Shows no research effort. Questioner did not even read `man du`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
du -d 1 -h
```

The `-d 1` option makes `du` report a depth of one level.

For a sorted output, you can add `| sort -h -k1` to the command.

example:

```
$ du -d 1 -h | sort -h -k1
8,0K    ./dir3
8,0K    ./dir1
5,0M    ./dir2
5,0M    .
```

Comment: You probably want `sort -h` instead of `sort -g`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
sudo du -h -d 1 /home
```

- `-h` enables human readable outputting of `du`
- `-d 1` (`--max-depth=1`) sets the maximum depth for traverse to 1, so as we are starting from `/home` only the individual home directories will be counted e.g. `/home/stu123`, `/home/stu124`